# add_filter to post-gallery and remove all <br>'s?

Tags: php, functions, filters

hey guys,
i really need your help.

Whenever I use a gallery in wordpress and set it's columns to just 1 Wordpress automatically adds `<br style="clear: both"/>` after every `<dl class="gallery-item">`. I really need to prevent this behaviour and therefore I'd like to add a filter to my functions.php

The following to examples don't work.

```
add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'remove_br_gallery', 9);

function remove_br_gallery($output) {

    return preg_replace('#\<br*.?\>#is', '',  $output);

}  


add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_br_gallery', 9);

function remove_br_gallery($output) {

    return preg_replace('#\<br*.?\>#is', '',  $output);

}
```

Neither does this:

```
return str_replace('<br style="clear: both">', '',  $output);
```

Any idea how I could solve that? I just don't want to have any `<br style="clear: both"/>` inside of my galleries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT:
you must call your filter after the shortcode is processed, giving it priority > 10,  and you must match on a multiline expression.

Try this work with my installation and using the standard gallery shortag:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'remove_br_gallery', 11, 2);
function remove_br_gallery($output) {
    return preg_replace('/<br style=(.*)>/mi','',$output);
}
```

Comment: thank you, but doesn't work! If I apply that function to the_content the entire content is gone. If I apply it to post_gallery nothing happens.

Comment: Try `preg_replace('/'.preg_quote('<br\s+style="\s*clear\s*:\s*both[;]{0,1}\s*"[/]{0,1}>', '/').'/Ui', '', $output);`.

Comment: ok...to simplify, i usually just do this: `'/\<br[^\>]*\>/'`

Comment: thank you it works. but only with the updated version of @keatch and the regexp of @wyrfel. Thank you both for your help. Awesome. Thank you

Comment: Yay...teamwork! ;-)

Comment: might there be a way to add this function specificly to the post_gallery. Because right now ALL <br>'s with a style get removed from the_content. That can be quite annoying when other wordpress plugin etc. use <br>'s to layout elements. Do you see a way to do that?

Comment: Uhm ... gallery is a shortcode, it post_gallery is a filter to replace all the gallery code, if you want override it. You can try the plugin that @kucrut suggest or follow this tutorial: http://dojo.codegreene.com/2009/filter-images-from-wordpress-gallery/. Remember that you are rewriting all the [gallery] shortcode code!

Comment: This parses all content, not just the gallery.

Answer (score 3):

Or, alternatively, you could try disabling the effect of the `<br>`'s via a stylesheet override, for instance:

`body dl.gallery-item + br { display: none; }`

Comment: thank you, that works fine. I'm already doing that - and I'm even using jquery to remove() the br element. I just thought there might be a way so the br's doesn't even get set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Justin Tadlock's [Cleaner Gallery](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cleaner-gallery/) plugin to get clean markup.

Answer (score 0):

Preg replace should contains apostrophes.

```
return preg_replace('/<br style="(.*)">/mi','',$output);
```